Error during signup: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
I'm deploying a Node.js application and a MongoDB instance in a Kubernetes cluster using kind. The Node.js application is exposed via a NodePort service. However, I'm encountering a connection timeout error when the application tries to connect to MongoDB:
Error during signup: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms



const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');
const sharp = require('sharp');
const { S3Client, DeleteObjectCommand, PutObjectCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();

// AWS S3 configuration
const s3 = new S3Client({
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    },
});

// Multer configuration for S3
const upload = multer({
    storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
});

// Connect to MongoDB with retry logic
const connectWithRetry = () => {
    console.log('Attempting MongoDB connection...');
    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    auth: 'none',
        connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
        socketTimeoutMS: 45000
    })
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected'))
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('MongoDB connection error:', err);
        console.log('Retrying MongoDB connection in 5 seconds...');
        setTimeout(connectWithRetry, 5000);
    });
};

connectWithRetry();

// Define a schema
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    phno: String,
    password: String,
    address: String,
    imageUrl: String,
    smallImageUrl: String,
    additionalAddresses: [{
        address: String,
        phno: String,
        imageUrl: String,
        smallImageUrl: String,
    }]
});

// Define a model
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Debugging middleware to log incoming requests
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`Incoming ${req.method} request to ${req.url}`);
    next();
});

// Serve static files
app.use(express.static('views'));

// Routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/login');
});

app.get('/signup', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'signup.html'));
});

app.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const newUser = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            phno: req.body.phno,
            password: req.body.password,
            address: req.body.address,
        });

        await newUser.save();
        res.redirect('/login');
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(`Error during signup: ${err.message}`);
    }
});

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'login.html'));
});

app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password });
        if (user) {
            res.redirect('/add-more');
        } else {
            res.status(401).send('Invalid login credentials');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(`Error during login: ${err.message}`);
    }
});



          

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});


this is my deplyment code to run in kubernetes cluster
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nodejs-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nodejs
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nodejs
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nodejs
          image: kiranrepository2023/nodejsapp:v22
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          env:
            - name: PORT
              value: "3000"
            - name: MONGO_URL
              value: "mongodb://root:example@mongodb-service:27017/signupDB?authSource=admin"
            - name: AWS_REGION
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: app-config
                  key: AWS_REGION
            - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: aws-secrets
                  key: aws_access_key_id
            - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: aws-secrets
                  key: aws_secret_access_key
            - name: AWS_BUCKET_NAME
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: app-config
                  key: AWS_BUCKET_NAME
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nodejs-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nodejs
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 30010
  type: NodePort


deployment code to use mongodb image to run nodejs application
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongodb
          image: mongo:4.4
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "2Gi"
              cpu: "1"
            limits:
              memory: "4Gi"
              cpu: "2"
          env:
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-username
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-password
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: app-config
                  key: MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
  type: ClusterIP

Questions:

What could be causing the buffering timed out error in this setup?

Are there any additional configurations needed for MongoDB or Node.js to work seamlessly in a Kubernetes environment?

How can I further debug or resolve this issue?


Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

In mongo url mongodb-service is replaced with mongo in docker-compose file
